# Multiple subnets in a GCP network

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, vpc, google-vpc

Subnets are regional resource, while network are global resource. I am doing a Google LAB and I am facing up this doubt.

There is this kind of network:
`networkA` with `subnet-a` and `subnet-b` both in region `us-central1`

How is it possible?

Comment: subnetwork are simple network range reservation. Limited to 1 region and thus can't mix resources from different region. That's all!! Then you will be able to route or filter with firewall rules traffic coming from a specific IP range, your subnet. Usually, all resources with the same concern/topology should be added in the same subnetwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see no issue with such configuration.

Please have a look at the documentation [Networks and subnets](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#vpc_networks_and_subnets):

> **Each VPC network consists of one or more** useful IP range partitions called **subnets**. Each subnet is associated with a
> region.

and

> **A network must have at least one subnet** before you can use it. Auto
> mode VPC networks create subnets in each region automatically. Custom
> mode VPC networks start with no subnets, giving you full control over
> subnet creation. **You can create more than one subnet per region**.

So, accordingly to the documentation, it's possible to have a network `test-network` with two subnets `subnet-a` and `subnet-b` both in same region `us-central1`, for example:

```
$ gcloud compute networks create test-network --subnet-mode=custom --mtu=1460 --bgp-routing-mode=regional

$ gcloud compute networks subnets create subnet-a --range=10.0.1.0/24 --network=test-network --region=us-central1

$ gcloud compute networks subnets create subnet-b --range=10.0.2.0/24 --network=test-network --region=us-central1 

$ gcloud compute networks list
NAME          SUBNET_MODE  BGP_ROUTING_MODE  IPV4_RANGE  GATEWAY_IPV4
test-network  CUSTOM       REGIONAL

$ gcloud compute networks subnets list
NAME      REGION                   NETWORK       RANGE
subnet-a  us-central1              test-network  10.0.1.0/24
subnet-b  us-central1              test-network  10.0.2.0/24
```

In addition have a look at the documentation section [Communication within the network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#intra_vpc_reqs):

> **Except for the default network, you must explicitly create higher
> priority ingress firewall rules to allow instances to communicate with
> one another**. The default network includes several firewall rules in
> addition to the implied ones, including the default-allow-internal
> rule, which permits instance-to-instance communication within the
> network. The default network also comes with ingress rules allowing
> protocols such as RDP and SSH.

Please update your question if you have other doubts.